# Solve $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\tanh(x)}{\arctan(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\tanh(x)}{\arctan(x)}$.

What is the answer with L'hopital steps?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Well, the limit of $\arctan x$ as $x\to \infty$ is $\frac \pi 2$ (we need a value $c$ where $\tan t \to \infty$ as $t\to c$.  $\tan t=\frac {\sin t}{\cos t}$ so we need $\cos t\to 0$ and $\sin t > 0$ and $-\frac \pi 2 \le t \le \frac \pi 2$ and that is $\frac \pi 2$).  So $\frac {tanh \ x}{\arctan x}$ is not in indeterminate form so L'hopital can not be applied.

Comment: You can only use L'hopital on $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ if both $f, g$ tend to $0$ or both tend to $\pm \infty$.  As $\arctan x\to \frac \pi 2$ and $\tanh x \to 1$, L'hopital can not be applied.  But note.  As both limits exist and neither are $0$, we can have $\lim \frac {tanh \ x}{\arctan x} = \frac {\lim tanh\ x}{\lim \arctan x}$.

Comment: An interesting follow-up, and I'd expect this was asked on purpose by your teacher: try to compute the limit with L'Hôpital anyway, and check that you don't get the same value, that is L'Hôpital fails, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hôpital's rule/method is not required or applicable because both the numerator and denominator converge to nonzero values. The limit converges to $\frac{2}{\pi}$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Since both numerator and denominator have nonzero limits, we can compute the limit of the quotient as the quotient of the limits.

We have:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \tanh(x) = 1
$$
and:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Therefore:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\tanh(x)}{\arctan(x)} = \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{2}{\pi}
$$

Comment: Yes, that is more precise. Thank you. I've edited my response.

Comment: Well, you don't explain why L'Hopital is not applicable nor so you explain why the limit is $\frac 2\pi$ and you mistakenly state that it is because a limit exists that we shouldn't use L'Hopital.

Comment: Indeed. Poor original form. I responded hastily. Thank you. I've edited to address these issues.